# How to add two json data together in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have Json Curl Data representing Post and Comments and I  have  successfully retrieved and displayed them one after the other. below is the code for Retrieving Post and comments

```
function loadPost(){
    $.post(
        'post.json',
        function(response){
            $.each(JSON.parse(response).items, function(i,v){  
                $('.info').append('<li><div class="msg-lhs"><span>'+v.post_id+'</span> <span>'+v.courses+'</span> </div></li>');
            });
        }
   );

   function loadComment(){
       $.post(
           'comment.json',
           function(response){
               $.each(JSON.parse(response).items, function(i,v){  
                   $('.info').append('<li><div class="msg-lhs"><span>'+v.post_id+'</span> <span>'+v.comment+'</span> </div></li>');
               });
           }
       );
```

below is the Json Format output for post and comment

```
{"items":[{"post_id":"101","courses":"physics"},
{"post_id":"102","courses":"Biology"},
{"post_id":"103","courses":"Chemistry"},
{"post_id":"104","courses":"Geophysics"},
{"post_id":"105","courses":"GeoChemistry"}]}



{"items":[{"post_id":"101","comment":"This  physcis is cool"},
{"post_id":"101","comment":"love this course on physics"},
{"post_id":"102","comment":"Biology is the scientific study of living things"},
{"post_id":"103","comment":"chemistry is good"},
{"post_id":"103","comment":"chemistry is the study of matter and compounds etc"}]}
```

Now my problem is how can I append comments directly under posts with same post_id
when displaying json contents in javascript. can someone help me fix that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine your posts and comments to one data set before appending them to the list element.

Here is an example without using jQuery, but jQuery has similar methods like `filter`, `map` and `extend`. I'm sure you'll get the idea.

```js
var posts = '{"items":[{"post_id":"101","courses":"physics"},{"post_id":"102","courses":"Biology"},{"post_id":"103","courses":"Chemistry"},{"post_id":"104","courses":"Geophysics"},{"post_id":"105","courses":"GeoChemistry"}]}';
var comments = '{"items":[{"post_id":"101","comment":"This  physcis is cool"},{"post_id":"101","comment":"love this course on physics"},{"post_id":"102","comment":"Biology is the scientific study of living things"},{"post_id":"103","comment":"chemistry is good"},{"post_id":"103","comment":"chemistry is the study of matter and compounds etc"}]}';

var list = document.getElementById('info')
// assuming that you have your posts and comments json data
var comments = JSON.parse( comments ).items;
var posts = JSON.parse( posts ).items;

// check if a post has comments
var postHasComments = ( comments, post ) => comments
  .some( comment => comment.post_id === post.post_id )

// get comments for specifig post
var getComments = ( comments, post ) => comments
  .filter( comment => comment.post_id === post.post_id )
  .map( comment => `<span>${ comment.comment }</span>` )

// combine posts with comments
posts.map( post => ( Object.assign( {}, { post_id, courses } = post,
    { comments: ( postHasComments( comments, post ) ) ? getComments( comments, post ) : [] } ) )
)
// append posts with their comments to list
.forEach( item => { list.innerHTML += `
<li>
  <div class="msg-lhs" id="${ item.post_id }">
    <span>${ item.post_id }</span>
    <span>${ item.courses }</span>
    ${ ( item.comments.length ) ? `<br />${ item.comments.join('<br />') }` : '' }
  </div>
</li>`
})
```

```html
<ul id="info"></ul>
```

Comment: your logic is excellent but i will always like to call json files from external source like this var posts = 'post.json';
var comments = 'comments.json';

Comment: You can still do that. I was just trying to give an example on how you could combine them, after you requested your json data. You already have two functions that take care of getting the data. Just do not append them separately. Combine them first and then take care of appending the data to the DOM.

Comment: Please Sir, its  not showing anything. for post   i have tried  reading it externally as  <script type="text/javascript" src="post.json"></script> var posts =JSON.parse(response).items; but nothing shows up

Comment: You can't load a json file using `<script src="post.json">`. Simply use `$.getJSON( "post.json", function() {...` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the loadComment method after loadPost() response binding completed
2. in loadPost() response binding give postid to div
3. find the div in loadComment and bind the comments to div.

---

```
function loadPost(){
    $.post(
        'post.json',
        function(response){
            $.each(JSON.parse(response).items, function(i,v){  
                $('.info').append('<li><div class="msg-lhs" id="'+v.post_id+'"><span>'+v.post_id+'</span> <span>'+v.courses+'</span> </div></li>');
            });
            loadComment();
        }
   );

   function loadComment(){
       $.post(
           'comment.json',
           function(response){
               $.each(JSON.parse(response).items, function(i,v){  
                   $('.info').find("#"+v.post_id).append('<span>'+v.comment+'</span>');
               });
           }
       );
```

Comment: `$('.info').find("#"+v.post_id)` why, when you already have a faster ID selector...

Comment: For safe side, as the id's generating dynamically if some other controls have the same id.

Comment: on every `each` you're iterating all over the DOM trying to first find **all** `.info` classes and than search for a supposingly unique ID - over and over again. That's a too expensive process. And again ID should be unique. The best would be to `.promise` all the `$.getJSON` are done, than combine the returned object responses and do the job only once.